# When defer func evaluates its parameters

Tags: go, error-handling, defer-keyword

I am learning how defer behaves in golang, and want to use it to handle error when the function returns.

Code is as below:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "errors"

func main() {
    a()
}

func a() {
    var err error   
    defer func(){
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("1st defer: %s\n", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("1st defer: defer not error")
        }
    }()
    defer func(err error){
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("2nd defer: %s\n", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("2nd defer: defer not error")
        }
    }(err)

    err = errors.New("new error")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

The output:

```
2nd defer: defer not error
1st defer: new error
```

[Doc](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) says parameters are evaluated when the defer call is evaluated, which seems it should be consistent. Why 2 defer has different value for variable `err` and thusly different output? I know it is related to 2nd function has `err` as input parameter, but don't know why.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok I just figured out. If you pass any parameters to the defer func (like the 2nd defer function above), **those parameters are evaluated when the defer function is deferred, not when they are executed**. That means in my example `err` is still `nil` and has not been assigned to a new error yet.

on the other hand, in 1st defer above, `err` is not a parameter, but a variable in function `a`, and when 1st defer is executed, it has already been assigned to a new error.

Answer (score 11):

Another way is by using reference to original *err* variable

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a()
}

func a() {
    var err error
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("1st defer: %s\n", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("1st defer: defer not error")
        }
    }()
    defer func(err *error) {
        if *err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("2nd defer: %s\n", *err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("2nd defer: defer not error")
        }
    }(&err)

    err = errors.New("new error")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

And output is:

```
2nd defer: new error
1st defer: new error
```

Comment: This was super helpful. I couldn't get my database transaction rollback function to work since it was being passed an error in a deferred function, but once I started passing it the error pointer it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

There is another similar situation there is in case of `Defer Statement` and `Defer Function`. Please have look at the example below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    start := time.Now()
    time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
    defer func() { fmt.Println("Defer Function Elapsed Time: ", time.Since(start)) }() //Defer Function
    defer fmt.Println("Defer Statement Elapsed Time: ", time.Since(start)) //Defer Statement
    time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
}
```

**Output:**

> Defer Statement Elapsed Time:  3s
>
> Defer Function Elapsed Time:  6s

Try above in [go play](https://play.golang.org/p/5aWS4ApS2p1)

***This is because of in the `Deferred Statement` case the deferred call's arguments are evaluated immediately***
[refer doc](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12)